# should I wrap INADDR_ANY with htonl?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm examining existing code. I've found such line:

```
imr.imr_interface.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
```

What means that `INADDR_ANY` bytes are already in "TCP/IP network byte order" and can be used as is. However later i've found such line:

```
binda.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Here the author converts "a u_long from host to TCP/IP network byte order"

Why sometimes `INADDR_ANY` need to be wrapped by `htonl` and sometimes it is not required? Or this is just a mistake in the code i'm trying to understand?

Comment: htonl is a noop on most hardware, that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @mouviciel True enough, but read the discussion at the dupe to understand why you might choose to be clear and not force readers to be aware of those implementation details.

Comment: @bmargulies: not on x86 based, which is one of the most likely systems around here.